# Maximum number of integral roots in degree $d$ polynomial?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

Given $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb Z[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ such that

1. Each coefficient is bound in absolute value by $B$
2. Degree of each variable in any monomial is bound by $d$
3. Total degree is $d'$
4. $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z[x_1,\dots,x_n]$

then what is the maximum number integral roots $(y_1,\dots,y_n)\in\mathbb Z^n$ it can have such that in a $\ell$ length cube?

Comment: it's not clear where your hypercube is. Do you mean the convex closure of $(\pm\ell, \pm\ell,...,\pm\ell)$, or something else?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik That is the cube.

Comment: For constant $d'$, it is easy to prove a bound of the form $(2\ell)^{n-1}(1+o(1))$, which is sharp in view of the equation $x_1-x_2=0$. In fact, this is true even modulo a prime (Lang--Weil theorem). I suppose that the question is to get good dependence as $d'\to\infty$, right?